# Load tagging in query with FPNTagBundle

Tags: symfony, tags, symfony-2.1

Bundle docs explain how to load tagging of a simple object:

```
$this->tagManager->loadTagging($article);
```

But I need to load a list (ArrayCollection from doctrine query) of taggable resources with their tags. And later iterate over a collection in twig and print:
   Object: tag1, tag2, tag..n

Comment: Did you find a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but hopefully this answer will help someone, as I ran into the same issue trying to implement the tagging bundle. The problem is that your entity will have a private or protected property for tags, but the way the documentation reads on the bundle, there is no association mapping for this property, and it's not an actual field (column).  So trying to access the tags property or use the getTags method on your entity won't work, either in your controller or in Twig.  I feel like the documentation on the bundle may be missing some mapping annotations on the tags property, but I haven't been able to narrow down exactly what it should be.

I ended up taking the approach a couple others recommended by looping thru my entities in the controller, and loading the tagging using the tagmanager for each entity.  What I also did which turned out to be helpful was to add a setTags method to the entity that accepts an ArrayCollection, that way when looping thru the entities in your controller, you can set the Tags on each one, then access them in twig like you want to do.  For example:

**Add this setTags method to your entity:**

```
/**
 * @param ArrayCollection $tags
 * @return $this
 */
public function setTags(ArrayCollection $tags)
{
    $this->tags = $tags;

    return $this;
}
```

This will allow you to set the tags property from your controller.

**Then in your controller:**

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $posts = $em->getRepository('ContentBundle:Post')->findAll();

    // here's the goods... loop thru each entity and set the tags
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $post->setTags($this->getTags($post));
    }

    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('AppBundle::index.html.twig',array(
        'posts' => $posts
    ));
}

/**
 * @param Post $post
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
public function getTags(Post $post) {
    $tagManager = $this->get('fpn_tag.tag_manager');
    $tagManager->loadTagging($post);

    return $post->getTags();
}
```

The getTags method in this controller simply takes your entity and uses the tagmanager to find and return it's tags.  You'll see the loop in the index method that adds the tags to each entity.

**Then in Twig you can access your tags on each post in the loop:**

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
  {% for tag in post.tags %}
    <a href="{{ url('tag_detail',{'slug':tag.slug}) }}">{{ tag.name }}</a> 
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the collection in your controller, like this:

```
foreach($articles as $article){
    $this->tagManager->loadTagging($article);
}
```

Comment: But I need do this inside twig template.

Comment: You will need to do this in your controller. After that you can iterate your collection in Twig as usual and you will get your articles tagged. I know, iterating twice over the same collection in the same request doesn´t look right, but I don´t think there is a better way to do it. If somebody knows I'd love to hear it, though.